# Difficulties setting the order of SVG images in HTML. Z-index not working

Tags: html, css, svg, z-index

Image of the card

[image: 1]

The top part of this card is a div with a blue background with three SVG images inside – the phone and the two half circles. With the phone I put the SVG directly in the HTML and I put the two half circles in using img tags.

I want the phone to appear in front of the two half circles.

I've tried using z-index (as you can see below) but for some reason it's not working. I've also tried moving the img tags above the svg.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The HTML:

```
<div class="illustration-box-top">
    <svg id="phone">
    </svg>
    <img src="..." class="illustration-box-circle-left"/>
    <img src="..." class="illustration-box-circle-right"/>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.illustration-box-top {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(103,125,209);
    background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(103,125,209,1) 30%, rgba(36,63,173,1) 100%);
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

#phone {
    z-index: 20;
}

.illustration-box-circle-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 19;
}

.illustration-box-circle-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 18;
}
```

Comment: You probably just need to add `position: relative` to the `#phone`

Comment: I honestly thought I had tried that! But yep, that did the trick!
Thanks!